# Auto generate fields in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am looking to auto-generate a new field by clicking an "add field" button.  I've looked into setting this up by introducing new variables in the domain class but does grails have a way to auto generate new fields using an onClick() method?

Comment: Another way I could go about this is if its possible to get names from one text field, possibly comma-delimited or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about clicking something in HTML and having it display a new INPUT element of type text to the user, no, there is nothing in Grails that does this for you.  But it isn't difficult.  Especially if you're using a decent JavaScript library like jQuery.

```
$('#addFieldBtn').click(function() {
   var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'text');
   $('#myForm').append(input);
});
```

That is a super simplistic version of what you might need.  And that is assuming I interpreted your question correctly.  You were pretty vague with details.

Comment: You got my question exactly right, I wasn't sure if I could incorporate JS into grails and read that input, thanks.